# How to make this container responsive (mobile/smaller devices) - Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I will apologize in advance for each a long post. I appreciate any suggestions/ideas! Thank you.

[image]

I'm having a problem with my layout breaking once it hits below 1200px (images and text drop down). I don't mind if they're aligned vertically in smaller browsers, as long as each time is correctly positioned below the correct heading.

Heading 1
8:00am
Lorem ispum
Lorem ispum
Lorem ispum

8:30am
Lorem ispum
Lorem ispum
Lorem ispum

Heading 2
9:00am
Lorem ispum
Lorem ispum
Lorem isum

And so on...

My question is, what would be the best way to make this work for mobile devices and smaller screens? I've been reading about Bootstrap's img-reponsive class and have applied it, but I don't see a difference in the image - it's possible I'm not using it correctly. I guess I was thinking it would shrink the image.

Also, as seen in the screenshot, there are 3 headings and 4 times associated with them. What is the best way to align each heading with each time associated (heading 1 having two times). As it stands, the associated times with "Heading 2" and "Heading 3" are a little far to the left. I've tried adding padding/margin right to select "", however that doesn't seem to do the trick.

```
<div class='tours-information'>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-9'>
          <div id='schedule'>
            <h2>Schedule</h2>
              <!--- wrapper for each day -->
              <div class='clearfix'>
                <h3 class='rounded-heading'>Main heading</h3>
              </div>
                  <div class="media">
                    <h5 class="media-heading pull-left ">Heading 1</h5>
                    <img class="media-object pull-left img-responsive" src="img/long_blue_arrow.png" alt="..." />
                    <h5 class="media-heading pull-left">Heading 2</h5>
                    <img class="media-object pull-left img-responsive" src="img/short_blue_arrow.png" alt="..." />
                    <h5 class="media-heading pull-left">Heading 3</h5>
                 </div>

                 <div class='schedule-location'>
                  <div class='col-md-3'>
                    <h4>8:00am</h4>
                    <div class='schedule-address'>
                      <address>
                      Lorem ispum<br>
                      Lorem ispum<br>
                      <span class='schedule-location-name'>(Lorem ispum)</span>
                    </address>
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </div>

                <div class='schedule-location'>
                  <div class='col-md-3'>
                    <h4>8:30am</h4>
                    <div class='schedule-address'>
                      <address>
                      Lorem ispum<br>
                      Lorem ispum<br>
                      <span class='schedule-location-name'>(Lorem ispum)</span>
                    </address>
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </div>

                <div class='schedule-location'>
                  <div class='col-md-3'>
                    <h4>9:00am</h4>
                    <div class='schedule-address'>
                      <address>
                      Lorem ispum<br>
                      Lorem ispum<br>
                      <span class='schedule-location-name'>(Lorem ispum)</span>
                    </address>
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </div>

                <div class='schedule-location'>
                  <div class='col-md-3'>
                    <h4>10:00am</h4>
                    <div class='schedule-address'>
                      <address>
                      Lorem ispum<br>
                      Lorem ispum<br>
                      <span class='schedule-location-name'>(Lorem ispum)</span>
                    </address>
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </div>

                <span>&nbsp;</span>
               <div class="media">
                    <h5 class="media-heading pull-left ">Heading 1</h5>
                    <img class="media-object pull-left img-responsive" src="img/short_blue_arrow.png" alt="..." />
                    <h5 class="media-heading pull-left">Heading 2</h5>
                    <img class="media-object pull-left img-responsive" src="img/long_blue_arrow.png" alt="..." />
                    <h5 class="media-heading pull-left">Heading 3</h5>
                 </div>

                <div class='schedule-location'>
                  <div class='col-md-3'>
                    <h4>8:30am</h4>
                    <div class='schedule-address'>
                      <address>
                      Lorem ispum<br>
                      Lorem ispum<br>
                      <span class='schedule-location-name'>(Lorem ispum)</span>
                    </address>
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </div>

                <div class='schedule-location'>
                  <div class='col-md-3'>
                    <h4>8:30am</h4>
                    <div class='schedule-address'>
                      <address>
                      Lorem ispum<br>
                      Lorem ispum<br>
                      <span class='schedule-location-name'>(Lorem ispum)</span>
                    </address>
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </div>

                <div class='schedule-location'>
                  <div class='col-md-3'>
                    <h4>9:00am</h4>
                    <div class='schedule-address'>
                      <address>
                      Lorem ispum<br>
                      Lorem ispum<br>
                      <span class='schedule-location-name'>(Lorem ispum)</span>
                    </address>
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </div>

                <div class='schedule-location'>
                  <div class='col-md-3'>
                    <h4>10:00am</h4>
                    <div class='schedule-address'>
                      <address>
                      Lorem ispum<br>
                      Lorem ispum<br>
                      <span class='schedule-location-name'>(Lorem ispum)</span>
                    </address>
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </div>

#schedule {
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  padding: 2px 25px 25px;
}

#schedule img {
  margin-top: 3px;
}

#schedule h2 {
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#schedule h3 {
  font-size: 28px;
}

#schedule h4 {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.rounded-heading {
    display:block;
    clear:right;
    float:left;
    padding: 1.5%;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    border-radius:10%;
    -moz-border-radius:10%;
    -webkit-border-radius:10%;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10%;
    background:#eee;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the `row` class. See the Bootstrap docs here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid remember you can combine class' to fine tune your layout on smaller devices.

e.g `<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">` will make your layout go from 4 to 2 columns on devices ≥768px and then to single column on phones.